# How do I load a element into a page within my own parameters

Tags: javascript, velo

Goals

- control when this Button element fades back into the webpage
- open a URL of choice in a new window.

Current Results:

- Element fades away after the on-click event hide function runs but does NOT come back without having to refresh the page.

Test:

- I've tried to use letShow to allow a timer (not much success, I'm very new to Javascript.) It also did not work for my needs.

Code:

```
export function ElementName_click(event) {
    $w("#ElementName").hide("fade");        
}
```

Comment: Still stuck, yes I have googled on this quite a bit :(

Comment: Got it fixed using a timer function with the help of a friend.